# WiFi card hard blocked on Medion Akoya E6214

Tags: wireless

I have a problem with my laptop's WiFi card, which was working flawlessly last week. I've tried different solutions I found here but I can't unblock the WiFi card. I also tried to switch and use a external dongle, the dongle is recognized but won't work. The dongle works in Windows and the native WiFi card doesn't. I tried to reset the BIOS as a last resort after trying to unblock via `rfkill` but my card is still hard blocked.

Laptop : Medion Akoya E6214.

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

0 is the actual WiFi card, 1 is the dongle

Output of `lsmod | grep wmi`:

```
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof
```

Also I already tried as suggested below the <kbd>Fb</kbd> keys, the others  keys work fine like, for example, volume, screenshots, etc., only the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to enable the WiFi doesn't seem to work. The little LED doesn't light up except for a brief moment at the boot time.

Comment: thank you very much chili555 , and Nmath yes because a week ago my wifi card was running flawlessly on this laptop

Comment: @muzeh *The dongle works in Windows and the native WiFi card doesn't* tells us something is wrong with the internal one. I suggest you try the FN+F7 switch in Windows and as last hope check if maybe it was disabled in BIOS/UEFI for some reason. If after all this it doesn't work in Windows as well it's surely defective.

Answer (score 0):

According to page 57 of [the manual](https://www.medion.com/gb/service/_lightbox/handbuch_details.php?did=9024) Wireless LAN is an optional feature. This function allows you to create a wireless network link with an access point or directly with another wireless-enabled PC. Using the key combination <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> you can enable or disable the wireless LAN function. A corresponding LED will light. Clearly this will not work if the optional feature isn't installed in your system. The wifi card is typically found under a panel on the underside of the laptop and if installed will look similar to this:

[image: wifi card]

When `rfkill list` reports that a card is hard blocked and the card exists, this has in my experience meant that the switch controlling the wifi card is off and needs to be toggled.

Sometimes the function keys on your keyboard could be locked by the F lock key. As a result, you can't use function keys. Check if there was any key like F Lock or F Mode key on your keyboard. If there is one key like that, press that key and then check if the Fn keys could work. Where the Fn is on your keyboard can be found in the manual linked above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tried  the fn keys , the others keys work fine ex : volume ,Screenshots etc ... only the fn key + f7 to unlock the wifi doens't seem to work the liltle led doesn't light up except for a brief moment on the boot up of the laptop